# Is there a way to pass an custom object to Spring State Machine and return an object at the end?

Tags: java, spring, state

Im a beginner to Spring State Machine. I have a requirement to perform multiple States like below.

Ex: Initial --> Create product --> Packing --> Shipping

I need to pass in an object from the main method to the "Create product"  or "Initial" state and at the end "Shipping" state should return the object to the main method.

Is there a possible way in spring state machine to do this?

Comment: I am also interested in this. Did you find anything about this topic?

Comment: I have moved on to use the state design pattern and solve this. So much of gray areas in Spring state machine. So didn't wanted to take risk